# What's the best way to store epub books?

Tags: ios, core-data, epub

So, I know that .ebook format is the same as .zip and before to read the book I should unzip .epub file to some directory of app. And here I have got some problems. What should I do with the unzipped files and just original .epub file? What should I delete after reading and closing the book? What should I save, unzipped files or .epub file?
Here some decision:

1) Saving ebub files in Core Data and when I intend to read a book I unzip the relevant epub file, parse it and display content. After reading has done unzipped files are deleting.

2) After downloading epub file I unzip it, save unzipped files on device (in some file directory or core data, I don't know which is the best choice) and delete epub file. As a result I have unzipped files and I can appeal directly (maybe this version is not the best by memory performance)

Which is the better or maybe there's another alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store it in CoreData -- put the files in Documents folder and store relative paths in CoreData (never store absolute paths in iOS -- they aren't stable).

To start, unzip the files and delete the zip.  If you want to save space, you can rezip.

If you find you are always out of space, there are ways that can read uncompressed streams right out of a zip (unzipping partially into memory) -- but this is overkill until you know that you need it.

Comment: I'm little bit confused by relative and absolute paths. What's difference between them?

Comment: An absolute path starts with / and it specifies a folder from the root folder. A relative path is appended onto an absolute path to obtain a new absolute path.